# Error in PHP file for Ajax response

Tags: php, ajax

I found this helpful example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started
that shows how to work with data using Ajax.  However, the article does not give details about what the PHP file should contain to make the example actually work.

I have tried this:

```
<?php
$name = (isset($_POST['userName'])) ? $_POST['userName'] : 'no name';
$computedString = "Hi, " . $name;
echo json_encode($computedString);
?>
```

And variations thereof, to no avail.  The result is a message box that says undefined.  What should be in the PHP file for this example to make it work?

Here is the HTML page, complete with the JS:

```js
<label>Your name: 
  <input type="text" id="ajaxTextbox" />
</label>
<span id="ajaxButton" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline">
  Make a request
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("ajaxButton").onclick = function()
  {
 var userName = document.getElementById("ajaxTextbox").value;
 makeRequest('test.php',userName);
  };

  function makeRequest(url, userName)
  {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest)
 {
      alert('Giving up - cannot create an XMLHTTP instance.');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
 httpRequest.open('POST', url);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    httpRequest.send('userName=' + encodeURIComponent(userName));
  }

  function alertContents()
  {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
 {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200)
   {
        //alert(httpRequest.responseText);
  try
  {
   var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
   console.log(e.message + " in " + httpRequest.responseText);
   return;
  }
  alert(response.computedString);
      }
   else
   {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
})();
</script>
```

EDIT:
The alertContents() function was modified as follows:

```js
  function alertContents()
  {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
 {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200)
   {
        //alert(httpRequest.responseText);
  console.log(response);
  console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
  var response = "default message";
  try
  {
   response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
  }
  catch(e)
  {
   console.log(e.message + " in " + httpRequest.responseText);
   
   return;
  }
  alert(response.computedString);
      }
   else
   {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
```

The first console.log line is line #44 in the script.  Rerunning the program and looking in the Console here is what happens:
[image]

When

```js
console.log(response);
```

is commented out this is the result:
[image]

ANOTHER EDIT:
The problem does indeed appear to have been in the PHP script.  Here is the updated PHP script and the result:

```html
$name = (isset($_POST['userName'])) ? $_POST['userName'] : 'no name';
$computedString = "Hi, " . $name;
$array = ['computedString' => $computedString];
echo json_encode($array);
```

[image]

A further improvement:

```html
$array = ['userData' => $name, 'computedString' => $computedString];
```

results in:
[image]

Comment: The `undefined` sounds like a JS issue. Can you post the JS?

Comment: Look at jQuery's website. Lots of examples there. :-)

Comment: Learning by Debugging. Request the php file with your browser and see what happens. Try different inputs and compare the outputs to your expected results.

Comment: @Jonas w: When the PHP script is requested with the browser this is displayed on the screen: "Hi, no name".

Comment: The fact that the PHP script gives an acceptable result when called in the browser supports @chris85's suggestion that it's a JS issue.  But what is the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Based on my understanding with your comments, it looks liek your PHP file is not returning the JSON response. It is returning the text whihc you passed from your form. So your responseText is simple string.

Hence, when you are trying to read it's property, it is undefined. Try the following code now.

```
function alertContents()
  {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
    {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200)
      {
          if(httpRequest.responseText == '')
           {
                alert('Error in code');
                return;
           }
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);

      }
      else
      {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
```

**Original:**
There is an issue with the variable scope in your code.

```
var response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
```

Here, you are defining **response** as a variable inside the **try** block and then trying to **alert** outside the block. That is why it is *undefined*.

Either you should move the alert statement inside the **TRY** block or define the variable outside.

```
 function alertContents()
  {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
    {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200)
      {
        //alert(httpRequest.responseText);

        var response = "Some default message";
        try
        {
            response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log(e.message + " in " + httpRequest.responseText);
            return;
        }
        alert(response.computedString);
      }
      else
      {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I made this change to the code but still get the same "undefined" message box.

Comment: use console.log(response) and let me know what does it show in the console area.

Comment: And are you getting the httpRequest.responseText as expected ? use console.log(httpRequest.responseText) as well.

Comment: Where should that line go in the code?  Sorry, I'm a newbie at JS/Ajax.

Comment: When alert(httpRequest.responseText); is uncommented the code works properly - a message box pops up that says "Hi, Joe" when Joe is entered in the text box.

Comment: share your code in test.php. I assume something like                 echo 'Hi ' .htmlspecialchars($_GET["userName"])

Comment: The code in test.php is the same as in the original post.  I tried the code in your updated post and it displays a message box that says "Hi, Joe".  However, I'm trying to get data back from the PHP script that is JSON rather than plain text.